# Orientdb : database closed exception while fetching records

Tags: orientdb, orientdb3.0

Trying to fetch records from orientdb. I am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Database 'remote:localhost/testdb' is closed
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentAbstract.checkOpenness(ODatabaseDocumentAbstract.java:2328)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentRemote.fetchNextPage(ODatabaseDocumentRemote.java:446)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.message.ORemoteResultSet.fetchNextPage(ORemoteResultSet.java:52)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.message.ORemoteResultSet.hasNext(ORemoteResultSet.java:47)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.executor.OResultSet.tryAdvance(OResultSet.java:41)
at java.util.Spliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:326)
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.executor.OResultSet.forEachRemaining(OResultSet.java:49)
at aoa.services.impl.OrientdConnectionHandler.getResultList(OrientdConnectionHandler.java:197)
at aoa.services.impl.OrientdConnectionHandler.main(OrientdConnectionHandler.java:209)
```

Querying data using below code :

```
   ...
    try(ODatabaseSession ses_orient = getConnPool(dbnae).acquire();){
      rs = ses_orient.query(query);  
    }


    public ODatabasePool getConnPool(String dbname){
      ODatabasePool pool = new 
       ODatabasePool(orientDB,dbname,OrientDbConFactory.USER,OrientDbConFactory.PASSWORD, 
       orientDBConfig);
       connPool.put(dbname,pool);
       return pool;
    }
   ...
```

The query works fine if I limit number of records to 1000 which is 'QUERY_REMOTE_RESULTSET_PAGE_SIZE'. If number of records is more than 1000, I am getting error : Database 'remote:localhost/testdb' is closed

Comment: can you change the title: you're not using the JDBC driver of Orientdb

Comment: the ses_orient is closed by the try (with resource), so is the rs. YOu should consume the rs inside the try block. I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are consuming the OResultSet outside the Try block, this means that the session is closed and the `rs` can't fetch more data from the database anymore.

```
 try(ODatabaseSession ses_orient = getConnPool(dbnae).acquire();){
     OResultSet rs = ses_orient.query(query);
     rs.stream()
        .forEach(x -> System.out.println(x.getProperty("propertyName")));
     rs.close();

}
```

Reference documentation:

http://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/java/Java-Query-API.html

Comment: Yes, that was the thing. I was fetching data from OResultSet after session was closed.